# Birt edition with two output streams

Tags: jakarta-ee, pdf-generation, birt, outputstream

I have a birt edition launched from a Java EE application, when the user launches the action, pdf generation launches in a new window, all of it works well, changes I want to make is this: I want to keep the same pdf in my server to send it in email  later.

```
PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption(options);
pdfOptions.setOutputFormat("pdf");
options.setSupportedImageFormats("JPG;BMP;PNG;JPEG");
pdfOptions.setOutputFileName(OUTPUT_LOCATION + "project/exportprojet.pdf");
pdfOptions.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(pdfOptions);
```

after adding `pdfOptions.setOutputFileName(OUTPUT_LOCATION + "project/exportprojet.pdf");`, the pdf is generated and stocked in the server, but what worked before is not working anymore, a new window is launched to the user and the pdf is not displayed, it looks like the added line took the generated pdf and put in the server by preventing it from going to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the implementation of the solution proposed by [hvb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700508/birt-edition-with-two-output-streams/28713257#28713257)  works perfectly, following changes made to my old code :

```
 PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption(options);
String sUrlExportFile = OUTPUT_LOCATION + "projet/" + idProjetAGenerer + "/exportprojet.pdf";
pdfOptions.setOutputFormat("pdf");
options.setSupportedImageFormats("JPG;BMP;PNG;JPEG");
pdfOptions.setOutputFileName(sUrlExportFile);
runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(pdfOptions);
runAndRenderTask.getAppContext().put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_BIRT_VIEWER_HTTPSERVET_REQUEST, request);
runAndRenderTask.run();
runAndRenderTask.close();
//copy the genereted file to response.getOutputStream()
File f = new File(sUrlExportFile);
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `setOutputFileName` and `setOutputStream` at the same time is not supported.

But the solution is obvious:
Just generate the PDF to the file system (using `setOutputFileName`), wait until your `RunAndRenderTask` is done, and then copy the file's content (binary) to the `response.getOutputStream`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just added the lines of code that implements your proposal, thank you to validate my modification to mark your answer as accepted :)